# Format number from polygon

Tags: flutter, dart, polygon

How to format the polygon token result?

I'm using this API

https://docs.polygonscan.com/api-endpoints/tokens

Let's say I have 14442 token in my wallet, the result returned in API is `14442000000000000000000`.

How should I format the result so it will display as 14442 in app? I'm usng Flutter.

Comment: Try parsing the number using [the decimal package](https://pub.dev/packages/decimal). `Decimal.parse('My_Big_Num') / (Decimal.parse('10').pow(18))`

Comment: @ShriHariL The argument type 'Rational' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Decimal'

Answer (score 0):

Since the number is large than the Number limit, you can use [Decimal](https://pub.dev/documentation/decimal/latest/decimal/Decimal-class.html) package to parse.

Example:

```js
var token = "14442000000000000000000"
var exponent = Decimal.fromBigInt(BigInt.from(10).pow(18));

/* pow(18) because it's mentioned in the doc. */

var result = Decimal.parse(token) / exponent;
```